# Validation for more than 1 space character

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am working on 1 project and there is 1 form in it where i need validation with appropriate message if validation fails

validation is for format check. I need to check if user enter words with more than 1 space character in it. i mean

if user enter

```
"hello    world"
```

then it should show "invalid format". The correct format should be

```
"hello world"
```

I mean only 1 space character is allowed.

I have tried this

```
validates_format_of :name, :with => /\s/
```

but it shows error when there is no space character....

Comment: I'd check the input in the form with JavaScript, and strip multiple spaces there, before submitting. An alternate is to `squeeze(' ')` or `squish` the string, rather than throw it back at the user after they've submitted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
validates_format_of :name, :without => /\s{2,}/, :message => "invalid format"
```

Note that `\s` matches any whitespace characters, which includes newlines, tabs, etc. as well as spaces. If you just want to match two or more spaces (and not two or more whitespace characters), then this would be better:

```
validates_format_of :name, :without => /\ {2,}/, :message => "invalid format"
```

Comment: Thanks shioyama for your effort, but its working in another way, i mean i shows "invalid format" when there is 0 or 1 space, whereas in case of more then 1 space character its perfect.

Comment: Are you sure you have `without` and not `with`? I've tested this and it works. Please check that you have `:without => /\s{2,}/` and not `:with => /\s{2,}/`.

Comment: Oh... You are right shioyama, It was my mistake, it was "with" in place of without..... Thanks a lot, Its done